# Express not working in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I've been trying to create an express project using WebStorm but here is the error message I get:

```
error creating Node.js Express App. Time limit exceeded for command:
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install express-generator@4.14.0
Standard output:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-express-generator1191
`-- express-generator@4.14.0 
  +-- commander@2.9.0 
  | `-- graceful-readlink@1.0.1 
  +-- mkdirp@0.5.1 
  | `-- minimist@0.0.8 
  `-- sorted-object@2.0.0 
Standard error:
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\intellij-express-generator1191\package.json'
npm WARN intellij-express-generator1191 No description
npm WARN intellij-express-generator1191 No repository field.
npm WARN intellij-express-generator1191 No README data
npm WARN intellij-express-generator1191 No license field.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it could be getting hung up on the license property in your package.json file. Try adding `"private": true` or `"license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.md"` to your package.json and then do `npm install` again.

Reference: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json